# Using getDoc().then() inside of a loop Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to loop through an array and for each element in an array i want to use getDoc() and then add the data of the document to a new array. Basically to do this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    let items = [];
    for(const cart_item of cartItems){
        getDoc(doc(getFirestore(), 'tickets', cart_item.ticket_id)).then((ticket_item) => {
            items.push({...ticket_item.data()});
        });
    }
    console.log(items);
}, [cartItems])
```

However, the items array is still empty after a loop where i log it. I think that the issue is that the loop is not waiting for the getDoc() to return something and goes on. How to make it wait for the getDoc() to finish? I have been reading about async, await but i still don't understand how to handle it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try refactoring your code with an async function as shown below:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const getItems = async () => {
    // fetching all documents by mapping an array of promises and using Promise.all()
    const itemsDocs = await Promise.all(cartItems.map(c => getDoc(doc(getFirestore(), 'tickets', c.ticket_id)))
    // mapping array of document data
    const items = itemsDocs.map(i => i.data())
    console.log(items);
  }
  getItems();
}, [cartItems])
```

Comment: Do checkout @Frank's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70227061/13130697) for a detailed explanation about issues with original code.

Answer (score 4):

When you call `getDoc` it needs to make a call to the Firestore server to get your data, which may take some time. That's why it doesn't immediately return the document snapshot, but instead you use a `then()` callback that the Firestore SDK calls when it gets the data back from the server.

---

This sort of asynchronous call changes the order in which you code executes, which is easiest to see if we add some logging to the code:

```
console.log("Before loading data");
for(const cart_item of cartItems){
    getDoc(doc(getFirestore(), 'tickets', cart_item.ticket_id)).then((ticket_item) => {
        console.log("Got data");
    });
}
console.log("After starting data load");
```

Then you run this code, the logging output i:

> Before loading data
>
> After starting data load
>
> Got data
>
> Got data
>
> ...

This is probably not what you initially expected, but it perfectly explains why your `console.log(items)` shows an empty array: by that time none of the calls to `items.push({...ticket_item.data()})` have run yet, because the data is still being loaded from the server.

---

I noticed that Dharmaraj just posted an answer with the code for a working solution using `Promise.all`, so I recommend checking that out too.