# How do I add a .then to a firebase getDocs()

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to perform an operation after I retrieve all of the docs from firebase, but getDocs don't allow for .then.

There's a post that has an example but it's more than I think I need and I still don't understand how to implement the solution.

Here's the code:[Using getDoc().then() inside of a loop Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70226994/using-getdoc-then-inside-of-a-loop-firebase)

```js
    const q = this.itineraryService.findData(filters);

    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      this.array.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id});
    });
```

I'd like to be able to just add a .then to the last ) but it doesn't allow that.  So how can I wait until I get all of the docs before performing the next operation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `then` instead of `await`, that'd be:

```
getDocs(q).then((querySnapshot) => {
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    this.array.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id});
  });
});
```

This works because the [`getDocs` function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#getdocs) returns a `Promise<QuerySnapshot>`.

Comment: I want to wait until after the querySnapshot finishes retrieving all of the docs.

Comment: That you already do with `await`. You can't reliably combine `await` and `then`. This sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What isn't working about the code you shared that makes you think you need both `await` and `then`? Is there an error message?

Comment: You know...I think I see what I'm missing.  Is this line actually retrieving all of the docs?
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

I was under the assumption that the querySnapshot.forEach() is what I'd have to wait for but what I think you're saying is that all of the docs are already in querySnapshot, so there's not need to wait after that.

Comment: How about the .forEach?  I need to add data only to the 0 element after pushing all of the data to the array.  Is forEach a synchronous action?  Does it move to the next line of code before iterating over the snapshot?

Comment: A `QuerySnapshot` contains a snapshot of the query results, so of the documents you requested. That's why that method returns a `Promise` and `forEach` or `doc.data()` (for example) do not.